# Access and print AST from ply yacc

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc, ply

I'm doing an compiler of a language (C-minus) using ply to build lexer and parser. IN ply documentation is clear that build an AST is 'entirely up to the user' (https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn2):

> The output of yacc.py is often an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). However, this is entirely up to the user.

So, with my lexer and parser working properly, how can I build an AST reader (because as said in documentation, the output is an AST, so I just need to access it)? I'm trying with this code below, but I'm receiving just `None` as response.

AST code:

```
def dumpast(node):
    _dumpast(node)
    print('pass 3')
    print('')

def _dumpast(node, level=0):

    if isinstance(node, tuple):
        indent(level)
        nchildren = len(node) - 1

        print("(%s" % node[0], end='')

        if nchildren > 0:
            print(" ", end='')

        for c in range(nchildren):
            _dumpast(node[c+1], level+1)
            if c != nchildren-1:
                print(' ', end='')

        print(")", end='')
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        indent(level)
        nchildren = len(node)

        print("[", end='')

        if nchildren > 0:
            print(" ", end='')

        for c in range(nchildren):
            _dumpast(node[c], level+1)
            if c != nchildren-1:
                print(' ', end='')
        print("]", end='')
    else:
        print("%s" % str(node), end='')

def indent(level):
    print('')
    for i in range(level):
        print('  |',end='')
```

And `main.py`:

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
import ply.lex as lex
from tabulate import tabulate
import sys
from lexer import *
from parser import Parser
from ast import dumpast

lexer = lex.lex()
print('pass 1')
parser = yacc.yacc(module=Parser)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    dumpast(parser.parse(f.read(),lexer))
    print('pass 2')
```

Response:

> pass 1
> Nonepass 3
>
> pass 2

Am I doing something wrong? Or could anybody share an AST building tutorial to access ply?

Edit: including parser.py to show how parsing works:

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
import lexer
from state import state

class Parser():
    tokens = lexer.tokens

    def p_program(p):
        'program : declaration_list'
        state.ast = p[1]
        print('passou 4')

    def p_declaration_list(p):
        '''declaration_list : declaration_list declaration
                            | declaration'''
        if len(p) == 3:
            p[0] = p[1]
            p[0].append(p[2])
        else:
            p[0] = p[1]

    def p_declaration(p):
        '''declaration : var_declaration 
                       | fun_declaration'''
        state.ast = p[1]

    def p_var_declaration(p):
        '''var_declaration : type_specifier ID 
                           | type_specifier ID LBRACKET NUM RBRACKET'''
        if len(p) == 3:
            p[0] = ('ASSIGN', ('ID', p[1]))
        else:
            p[0] = ('ASSIGN', ('ID', p[1]), ('NUM', p[4]))

    def p_type_specifier(p):
        '''type_specifier : INT 
                          | VOID'''
        state.ast = p[1]

    def p_fun_declaration(p):
        'fun_declaration : type_specifier ID LPAREN params RPAREN compound_stmt'
        p[0] = ('ASSIGN', ('ID', p[1]), p[4], p[6])

    def p_params(p):
        '''params : param_list 
                  | VOID'''
        state.ast = p[1]

    def p_param_list(p):
        '''param_list : param_list COLON param 
                      | param'''
        if len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = p[1]
            p[0].append(p[3])
        else:
            p[0] = p[1]

    def p_param(p):
        '''param : type_specifier ID 
                 | type_specifier ID LBRACKET RBRACKET'''
        p[0] = ('ASSIGN', ('ID', p[1]))
        
    def p_compound_stmt(p):
        'compound_stmt : LKEY local_declarations statement_list RKEY'
        p[0] = (p[2], p[3])

    def p_local_declarations(p):
        '''local_declarations : local_declarations var_declaration
                              | empty'''
        if len(p) > 1:
            p[0] = (p[1], p[2])
        else:
            pass

    def p_statement_list(p):
        '''statement_list : statement_list statement
                          | empty'''
        if len(p) > 1:
            p[0] = p[1]
            p[0].append(p[3])
        else:
            pass

    def p_statement(p):
        '''statement : expression_stmt
                     | compound_stmt
                     | selection_stmt
                     | iteration_stmt
                     | return_stmt'''
        state.ast = p[1]
                    
    def p_expression_stmt(p):
        '''expression_stmt : expression SEMICOLON
                           | SEMICOLON'''
        if len(p) == 3:
            p[0] = p[1]
        else:
            pass

    def p_selection_stmt(p):
        '''selection_stmt : IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement 
                          | IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement ELSE statement'''
        if len(p) == 6:
            p[0] = ('IF', p[3], p[5], ('NIL',))
        else:
            p[0] = ('IF', p[3], p[5], p[7])

    def p_iteration_stmt(p):
        'iteration_stmt : WHILE LPAREN expression RPAREN statement'
        p[0] = ('WHILE', p[3], p[5])

    def p_return_stmt(p):
        '''return_stmt : RETURN SEMICOLON
                       | RETURN expression SEMICOLON'''
        if len(p) == 3:
            p[0] = ('RETURN',)
        else:
            p[0] = ('RETURN', p[2])

    def p_expression(p):
        '''expression : var EQUAL expression 
                      | simple_expression'''
        if len(p) > 2:
            p[0] = ('ASSIGN', (p[1], p[3]))
        else:
            p[0] = [p[1]]

    def p_var(p):
        '''var : ID 
               | ID LBRACKET expression RBRACKET'''
        if len(p) == 2:
            p[0] = ('ID', p[1])
        else:
            p[0] = (('ID', p[1]), [p[3]])

    def p_simple_expression(p):
        '''simple_expression : additive_expression relop additive_expression
                             | additive_expression'''
        if len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = (p[1], ('RELOP', p[2]), p[3])
        else:
            p[0] = [p[1]]

    def p_relop(p):
        '''relop : LESSOREQUAL
                 | LESS
                 | GREAT
                 | GREATOREQUAL
                 | DOUBLEEQUAL
                 | NOTEQUAL'''
        p[0] = ('RELOP', p[1])

    def p_additive_expression(p):
        '''additive_expression : additive_expression addop term 
                               | term'''
        if len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = (p[1], p[2], p[3])
        else:
            p[0] = p[1]

    def p_addop(p):
        '''addop : PLUS
                 | MINUS'''
        p[0] = p[1]
                 
    def p_term(p):
        '''term : term mulop factor 
                | factor'''
        if len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = (p[1], p[2], p[3])
        else:
            p[0] = p[1]

    def p_mulop(p):
        '''mulop : MULT
                 | DIV'''
        p[0] = p[1]

    def p_factor(p):
        '''factor : LPAREN expression RPAREN
                  | var 
                  | call 
                  | NUM'''
        if len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = p[2]
        elif p == 'NUM':
            p[0] = ('ASSIGN', ('NUM', p[1]))
        else:
            p[0] = p[1]

    def p_call(p):
        'call : ID LPAREN args RPAREN'
        p[0] = (('ID', p[1]), p[3])

    def p_args(p):
        '''args : arg_list 
                | empty'''
        if p == '':
            pass
        else:
            state.ast = p[1]

    def p_args_list(p):
        '''arg_list : arg_list COLON expression 
                    | expression'''
        if len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = p[1]
            p[0].append(p[3])
        else:
            p[0] = p[1]

    def p_error(p):
        if not p:
            print("SYNTAX ERROR AT EOF")

    def p_empty(p):
        'empty :'
        pass
```

Comment: There is no indication there of what your parser actually does, so it's impossible for us to say what it might return. The return value of `parse` is whatever was placed in `p[0]` by the action of the top-level reduction, so that's where you should start looking.

Comment: class parser included in question. it helps to understand what I'm asking for?

Comment: Sorry, I put an old version of parser.py. now I editted with correct version. i made little changes and still doesn't work. could you tell me if there's something wrong in this version?
and other question: when ply generate LALR tables doesn't mean that parser is correct? i imagined that.

Answer (score 0):

`parser.parse()` returns whatever was placed into `p[0]` by the top-level reduction action. Your top-level reduction action doesn't put anything into `p[0]`. So the parse function returns `None` and that's what you pass to your AST dumper.

It is not necessary to use state (or global) variables like `state.ast` in order to return a value from a Ply parser; that's a pattern which you might have copied from a solution for a different parser generator. I notice that you also assign to `state.ast` rather than setting `p[0]` in other actions where it cannot possibly be correct even in a parser generator which doesn't provide a more convenient mechanism to return a top-level result. Those also need to be corrected.

Comment: i don't understand, even without `state.ast` when i declare `p[0] = p[1]` nothing happens. and this is exactly what grammar says. how am i not putting anything in p[0]? this make no sense.

Comment: Well, it's possible that p[1] is None, because of a bug elsewhere. It's also possible that a parsing error occurred; since you only produce an error report if the error occurs at EOF, you have no way of knowing whether that happened.