# getting error: using debug in ply builder

Tags: python, parsing, debugging, compiler-errors, ply

I'm creating an compiler using ´ply´. Lexer and parser are done and in yacc builder I put a debug to see if it was working:

```
parser = yacc.yacc(module=Parser)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    parser.parse(input=f.read(), debug=1)
```

The return was a list with all tokens in input.txt and the error below:

```
State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(RKEY,'}',5,94)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(RKEY,'}',5,94)
```

Anyone call tell me what this error means and how I can fix it?

input.txt:

```
int gcd(int u) {
    if (v == 0) return u;
    else return gcd(v, u-u/v*v);
    /* comment */
}
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the error occurred earlier, putting the parser into panic-mode recovery. I noticed in [another question of yours]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065319/access-and-print-ast-from-ply-yacc) that you ignore errors which don't occur at the end of input, so it's quite possible that you missed the error report (although it should also appear earlier in the debug trace). But you shouldn't rely on people seeing your other questions: a SO question should be self-contained and include all relevant data, whether or not you think the information is relevant…

Comment: … which is why you should always provide a [mre], which is both *complete* and *minimal*.